# Dayname in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

I'm displaying a crystal report in C# with the following format:
1  2   3  4  5 ....31
based on date range.The days are displaying from the database.
I need to add dayname along with the days .Is there any function to display dayname in crystal report?

Answer (score 1):

`WeekdayName(DayOfWeek(yourDateField))` should work.